# Oracle stored procedure with multiple arrays and scalars from managed data access

Tags: c#, arrays, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am trying to call the following Oracle stored procedure from the Oracle managed data access client

```
PROCEDURE CLONE_PRODUCT(p_f_cloned_prod_id    IN      product.product_id%TYPE,
                        p_f_name              IN      product.name%TYPE,
                        p_f_desc              IN      product.presentation_value%TYPE,
                        p_f_sys_issue         IN      product.product_reference%TYPE,
                        p_f_feature_names     IN      T_CHAR_TAB,
                        p_f_feature_values    IN      T_CHAR_TAB,
                        p_f_audit_user        IN      product.last_updated_by%TYPE,
                        p_f_product_id           OUT  product.product_id%TYPE)
```

where

```
TYPE  t_char_tab  IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

with this C# code:

```
 using (var cloneProductCmd = new OracleCommand("SPF_SQL.CLONE_PRODUCT", con))
 {
     cloneProductCmd.BindByName = true;
     cloneProductCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_CLONED_PROD_ID", 1);
     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_NAME", "bob");
     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_DESC", "bob smith");
     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_SYS_ISSUE", 123);

     var featureNames = new OracleParameter()
     {
         ParameterName = "P_F_FEATURE_NAMES",
         Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
         OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
         Value = new string[] { "feature 1" }
     };
     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add(featureNames);

     var featureValues = new OracleParameter()
     {
         ParameterName = "P_F_FEATURE_VALUES",
         Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
         OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
         Value = new string[] { "value 1" }
     };
     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add(featureValues);
     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_AUDIT_USER", "me");
     cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_PRODUCT_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);

     cloneProductCmd.ArrayBindCount = 1;

     var reader = await cloneProductCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

     newProductId = Convert.ToInt32(cloneProductCmd.Parameters["P_F_PRODUCT_ID"].Value.ToString());
}
```

and I have tried changing the `ArraybindCount` to 2 (2 arrays of length 1) and also tried specifying that the array parameters have a `collectionType` of `PLSQLAssociativeArray`.

I always get an exception with the message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Array'

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6412367/2987400) answer and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featOraCommand.htm#i1007888) article suggest that the `ArrayBindCount` property means that the client is expecting an array for all parameters.

My question is how can I call a stored procedure passing in multiple scalar values and multiple arrays (all arrays are of the same number of elements) and also an out parameter (scalar)?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this, with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344214/2987400) answer I tweaked my code and got it to work.

in short the `ArrayBindCount` appear to be unecessary, but for each array parameter the `CollectionType, Size, ArrayBindSize and ArrayBindStatus` are necessary, I also created the parameters by directly adding to the `Parameter` collection of the command rather than creating them standalone and then adding them to the collection, not sure if that is relevant.

here is my working code:

```
using (var cloneProductCmd = new OracleCommand("SPF_SQL.CLONE_PRODUCT", con))
{
    cloneProductCmd.BindByName = true;
    cloneProductCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_CLONED_PROD_ID", product.OriginalProductId);
    cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_NAME", productName);
    cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_DESC", fullProduct.ProductName);
    cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_SYS_ISSUE", fullProduct.SystemIssueNumber);

    var featureNames = cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_FEATURE_NAMES", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    featureNames.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    featureNames.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    featureNames.Value = features.Select(_ => _.Key).ToArray();
    featureNames.Size = features.Count();
    featureNames.ArrayBindSize = features.Select(_ => _.Key.Length).ToArray();
    featureNames.ArrayBindStatus = Enumerable.Repeat(OracleParameterStatus.Success, features.Count()).ToArray();

    var featureValues = cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_FEATURE_VALUES", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    featureValues.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    featureValues.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    featureValues.Value = features.Select(_ => _.Value).ToArray();
    featureValues.Size = features.Count();
    featureValues.ArrayBindSize = features.Select(_ => _.Value.Length).ToArray();
    featureValues.ArrayBindStatus = Enumerable.Repeat(OracleParameterStatus.Success, features.Count()).ToArray();

    cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_AUDIT_USER", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    cloneProductCmd.Parameters.Add("P_F_PRODUCT_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);

    var reader = await cloneProductCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

    newProductId = Convert.ToInt32(cloneProductCmd.Parameters["P_F_PRODUCT_ID"].Value.ToString());
}
```